# Calculate value from an array and return total in another array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, numbers, calculator

I'm creating a project in which when I click on the Add button, I add the value entered in the first input to an array. After entering as many values ​​as possible I would like to calculate the numbers in the array and enter them in an array containing the total and show it in the console.

I was able to get the input values ​​to add to the array but can't calculate them afterwards. Can anyone kindly tell me how can I do?

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stile.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form>

        <div>
            <input type="number" id="importo">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" id="aggiungi">AGGIUNGI</button>

        <button type="submit" id="calcola">CALCOLA</button>
    </form>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS

```
 const aggiungi = document.getElementById("aggiungi")

const calcola = document.getElementById("calcola")

const importazione = document.getElementById("importo")




const spese = []


console.log(importazione, motivazione)


aggiungi.onclick = function(e) {

e.preventDefault()

spese.push(Number(importazione.value))

console.log(importazione.value)

console.log(spese)
      
}





/* calcola.onclick = function (e) {

    e.preventDefault()

    let somma = 0

    let conti = []

    for (let i=0; i = spese.length; i++) {
        
        conti = [somma += spese[i]]

        console.log(conti)
      
    }

}  */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

> The reduce() method executes a user-supplied "reducer" callback function on each element of the array, in order, passing in the return value from the calculation on the preceding element. The final result of running the reducer across all elements of the array is a single value.
>
> The first time that the callback is run there is no "return value of the previous calculation". If supplied, an initial value may be used in its place. Otherwise the array element at index 0 is used as the initial value and iteration starts from the next element (index 1 instead of index 0).

```js
const aggiungi = document.getElementById("aggiungi")

const calcola = document.getElementById("calcola")

const importazione = document.getElementById("importo")

const spese = []


console.log(importazione);


aggiungi.addEventListener("click", e => {
  spese.push(Number(importazione.value))

  console.log(importazione.value)

  console.log(spese)

});

calcola.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const result = spese.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue, 0);

  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stile.css">
</head>

<body>

  <form>

    <div>
      <input type="number" id="importo">
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="aggiungi">AGGIUNGI</button>

    <button type="button" id="calcola">CALCOLA</button>
  </form>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What it means this reduce syntax?

Comment: There are any other methods to achieve the solution that I want?

Comment: I have edited my answer, but you can read everything in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Ok, but how JS know what are the value of previous and current value if this values are not defined?

Comment: They are defined. You get them in your reduce function `array.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => ...)`

Comment: If i have understand this method works like this:, the starting point is 0, the first value is 79.5, the second value is 56.78 so it add 0 + 79.5 (array element 0) + 56.78 (first element of iteration). If i have a third value the iteration add 0 + index 0 + the first element + the second element and so on, right?

Comment: Yes, in this case this is right.

Comment: No problem :-). If you have more questions, you are welcome to ask!